# How to visualize counts of different categories

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data

Suppose we have $10$ boxes and we are interested in measuring the number of apples, oranges and pears in each. What is a good way to visualize how the boxes relate to each other in terms of the distribution of fruits? For example, box 1 might have 5 apples, 10 oranges, and 6 pears while box 10 might have 1 apple, 1 orange and 1 pear.

**Added.** Is looking at a distance matrix appropriate? Is there a way to visualize a distance matrix?

Comment: With numbers so small, why is a table a bad option?

Comment: A table could work fine too.

Answer (score 4):

I agree broadly with Maarten, as a click on his link will imply, but other answers are possible.

Note first that many people would regard a spineplot as just a special case of a mosaic plot. Programs or functions in your favourite software are perhaps more likely to use the second term.

That said, a good old-fashioned bar chart or (Cleveland) dot chart can work as well here as anything else, although some designs are better than others. In particular, stacked (divided) bar charts divide the world: some love them, some hate them.

Pie charts? Just say no.

Yet further, your question leaves open quite what you want your graph to show. Do you want to emphasise frequencies or to emphasise proportions or (quite reasonably) to have it both ways? The `spineplot` implementation in Stata used by Maarten can show absolute numbers as well as conveying the fractional breakdown, and that's surely a standard feature in other environments.

Comment: Can you do it in SPSS?

Comment: Sorry, haven't used SPSS for about 30 years. Someone else may know.

Comment: Poster asked about whether a distance matrix would be useful. Depends on the problem and what kind of distance matrix. Your question is about visualizing a two-way table of counts. If you have some other question in mind, best to give us much more background.

Comment: SPSS has no native implementation of the spineplot @guestoiejroe (unfortunately there is no magical "Mosaic" coordinate system as Wilkinson displays in his *Grammer* book). I would suggest piggy-backing on the R `vcd` library (that is calling R code from SPSS). While I am here though, I was working on an implementation of one the other day in SPSS, so a question to Dr. Cox - how do you do your default ordering of the categories?

Comment: @Nick Cox: I want to see how similar a box is to another box. So it seems that using a Euclidean distance similarity matrix would be good.

Comment: @Andy W: In my Stata program, the variables on the sides of the plot are ordered as they come, numeric order or alphabetic order for strings. If someone wanted a different order, they'd need to recode the variables. I don't know why Maarten had the order "orange" "pear" "apple"; perhaps he's thinking in Dutch then translating back to English (serious comment; I know him).

Comment: @guestoiejroe: I see. Sounds like a complicated way to answer a simple question to me, but don't take that too seriously.

Answer (score 3):

What about a [spineplot](http://econpapers.repec.org/software/bocbocode/s456885.htm)? That way you can simultaneously display both the differences in proportions per box and differences in the size of the boxes. Your example with two boxes would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you make spine plots in SPSS?